# Vue.JS nested v-for throwing null/undefined error

Tags: javascript, vue.js, single-page-application, axios

## Updated at end of question.

I have a Vue component with the following data:

```
conversations: null,
currentConversation: null,
```

and the following method, which runs on `mounted()`:

```
/**
 * Method to retrieve the user's conversations.
 */
getConversations() {
    axios.get('/api/user/conversations')
    .then((response) => {
        this.conversations = response.data;
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
    })
},
```

In the `<template>`, I display each conversation using the following:

```
<template v-for="conversation in conversations">
    <div class="conversation">
        <p>
            <!-- Template for each user -->
            <template v-for="(user, index) in conversation.users">
            {{ user.first_name }} {{ user.last_name }}<span v-if="index != (conversation.users.length - 1)">,</span>
            </template>
        </p>
    </div>
</template>
```

In the `<template>` for the current conversation, I am attempting to use the following:

```
<template v-for="message in currentConversation.messages">
    <div class="message">
        <div class="bubble">
            {{ message.content }}
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

When initially mounted, both `conversations` and `currentConversation` are null. The template for displaying `conversations` works fine. It's empty until the Ajax request returns the data. However, the `currentConversation` throws the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'messages' of null
```

The `currentConversation` object is later retrieved via Ajax when a user selects a conversation to view.

I have found that if I wrap the current conversation `<template>` in another `div` with a `v-if="currentConversation"` directive, the error does not show up, and the template renders properly. However, since I don't have to use the `v-if` hack on the conversations `<template>`, why would I need to use it on the current conversation `<template>`?

**Updated:** Thanks to @wing and @Traxo, initializing with an empty array works. However, I do not understand why I must set an empty array initially for `currentConversation`, but don't for `conversations`.

Comment: I didn't look too deep into the problem, but I think it's NOT `v-for` problem, I think it has something to do with nesting. If your data has more than 2 dimension you will get that error I think. (I temporarily solved my problem with `v-if` just like you did)

Comment: @Traxo I initially was thinking that could be some weird issue, but I don't see how that could be when both templates go the same levels deep to get data, but only one has issues. The issue with the `v-if` is that I shouldn't have to do it with one template but not the other.

Comment: you say "currentConversation throws the following error" but I don't see `.users` in there?

Comment: @Traxo I made a mistake, copied the wrong error. It should say `messages`. Updated question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**What is the problem?**

You initialise your `currentConversation` property with `null`.

> I have a Vue component with the following data:
>
> ```
> conversations: null,
> currentConversation: null,
> ```

`v-for="message in currentConversation.messages"` attempts to iterate over enumerable properties of `currentConversation.messages`.

However `currentConversation` is initially `null`. Hence

> `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'messages' of null`

**What can I do about this?**

You can initialise `currentConversation.messages` with an empty array.

```
currentConversation: {
  messages: [],
},
```

This is so that Vue can attempt to iterate over `currentConversation.messages` and give you a clear indication that `currentConversation` is supposed to have `messages`.

Comment: The problem is that I don't have to initialize conversations with an empty array and any of its nested properties. But with currentConversation, I do. Why would I have an issue with one but not the other, when they're doing the same things?

Comment: @joexanderson not same, in currentConversation case you are trying to get it's property e.g. null.messages, while in first case you are just trying to iterate through null, which is fine with vue.

Comment: @Traxo Okay, I understand now. Thanks for your help, I do appreciate it!

Answer (score 2):

```
currentConversation: {},
```

insted of

```
currentConversation: null,
```

Comment: Okay, so initializing with an empty array works. However, I don't understand why I must set an empty array for currentConversation, but don't for conversations.